# How to do lighting for endless runner game?

Tags: unity, lighting, lightmap

I have been working on a endless runner game for a month now and have to do basic lighting. In my game Player moves forward and world is being generated according to player position. So the positions of world is not fixed means I cannot have baked lights. Since Im not an artist and the game is for mobile so what should be the best approach to have a lighting setup for this type of game?

Also I have some 3D menu scenes like shop or character selection scene so I have setup baked light as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Kindly help for my endless runner scenes.

Comment: Do you have point-light sources in the game or only directional light? If all light is from a fixed directional position, you could cheat a lot by adding shading directly to the albedo textures of your models before you even import them into Unity.

Comment: Yes I only have a directional light. Can you explain little bit more about adding shading part? I have already imported the models and setup in the unity.

Comment: What I meant is that you open the textures in your favorite image editor and paint the shaded part darker and the lighted parts brighter. You essentially do the work of the shader manually. It is a lot of work, doesn't work when the UV maps are set up in a way that a lot of texture is reused, only works with objects which are not animated and always lit from the same direction, but if you can pull it off you can render it with an unlit shader and have the object look as if it was shaded.